# Update project window , IntelliJ-idea

Tags: intellij-idea

When I made commit I selected "Don't show this dialog next time".
I'd like to change update project options, but I don't know how to force IntelliJ to show this dialog again. I searched in IntelliJ Settings, but I didn't find anything for this issue.
Need help :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to Project Settings ( <kbd>Ctrl Alt S</kbd> ) then Version Control and Confirmation.

Answer (score 2):

File -> Settings (Ctrl Alt S)

Select Version Control -> Confirmation

Under fourth set of option with sub caption "Display options dialog when these commands are invoked", check UPDATE option.